# Correctly send object from <select> tag with Thymeleaf and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application (a library manager) that uses Thymeleaf as the template engine.

The application consists on two primary `@Component`s, `Book` and `Author`. A `Book` can have a single `Author`.

I can successfully Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete any `Author`, but can't Create or Update `Book`s correctly (though I can Retrieve and Delete them). When making the POST request to insert the `Book` (an insertion of an already existent object simply updates it) I get an `400 Bad Request. Validation failed for object='book'.` error in the browser, and the console lists a `typeMismatch: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.springboot.demoweb.model.Author'` error.

I was inspecting the requests sent to the application, and instead of sending a JSON "node" (sorry, I don't know how JSON works) containing the properties of `Author` inside the root JSON "node" `Book`, it simply sent the results of `Author.toString()` (that I overritten. Not overriding the method doesn't change anything).

Here is the `<select>` snippet:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/books}" th:object="${book}" method="post">
    ...

    <select th:field="*{author}">
        <option th:each="author : ${authors}"
                th:value="${author}"
                th:text="${author}"/>
    </select>

    ...
</form>
```

The `Author.java` file:

```
@Component
public class Author implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Calendar dateBorn;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Calendar dateDeath;

    ... // Getters and setters
}
```

The `Book.java` file:

```
@Component
public class Book {
    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private Author author;

    ... // Getters and setters
}
```

And `BookController.java`:

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/books/edit", params = "isbn")
    public String viewEdit(@RequestParam("isbn") String isbn, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("book", bookService.find(isbn));
        model.addAttribute("authors", authorService.all());
        return "books/edit";
    }

    // th:action="@{/books}" falls here
    @PostMapping("/books")
    public RedirectView create(Book book) {
        bookService.create(book);
        return new RedirectView("/books.html?isbn=" + book.getIsbn());
    }

    ... // Other mappings
}
```

The variables `bookService` and `authorService` do simple operations on a `Map<String, Book>` and `Map<String, Author>`, respectively.

What can I make for that Thymeleaf will send `Author` as an object inside `Book`, and not just the String representation of it? Do I have to change something in the HTML page? The Controller? Add a Thymeleaf configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the thymeleaf [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#handling-the-command-object),

> Values for th:object attributes in form tags must be variable expressions (${...}) specifying only the name of a model attribute, without property navigation. This means that an expression like ${seedStarter} is valid, but ${seedStarter.data} would not be.

Your Thymeleaf form renders toString value of the selected Author. It is not possible to bind Author objects in the options list. Therefore, change the Book object adding a new attribute *authorId* (if Book is a JPA entity, annotate this with @Transient).

```
@Component
public class Book {
     private String isbn;
     private String title;
     private Author author;
     // New Transient attribute to bind authorId from select component
     private String authorId;
}
```

Now, this new attribute can be bind using the select component as it complies with the above documentation.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/books}" th:object="${book}" method="post">
...

<select th:field="*{authorId}">
    <option th:each="author : ${authors}"
            th:value="${author.id}"
            th:text="${author.name}"/>
</select>

...
```

In your controller, you can get author object using book.authorId and set it to the book object.

```
@PostMapping("/books")
public RedirectView create(Book book) {
    Author author = authorService.findById(book.authorId);
    book.setAuthor(author);
    bookService.create(book);
    return new RedirectView("/books.html?isbn=" + book.getIsbn());
}
```

Comment: How can I do this? In the JSON the attribute "author" is with `Book` fields, so how do I access it?

Comment: I tried adding a `@ModelAttribute("author") String authorId` before the `Book` parameter but this didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the controller method handling th:action="@{/books}"

Comment: I edited the thread. Now it contains the method that handle `th:action="@{/books}"`

Comment: See above modified answer

Comment: Thanks man. By the way, if I ain't going to use JPA, do I need to mark the field as `transient`? Or is it completely unnecessary for the proper working of the system?

Comment: @taarak Yes you need to annotate it with Transient to avoid it to be persisted. The reason is Book entity has a oneToOne relationship to the Author entity. The authorId attribute in Bok object just facilitates to create this relationship.